# Eliminar el texto entre llaves de un nombre de usuario

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un juego como agar.io y se usan *PIELES*.

La *piel* se pone en el nombre del jugador con `{`...`}`. O sea, `{nombreDaLaPiel} Nickname`.

La función que esconde el nombre de la piel para que no se vea en el nombre

```
setName: function(name) {
  var reg = /\{([\w]+)\}/.exec(name);
  if (reg) if (reg.length === 2) {
    this.nameSkin = reg[1].toLowerCase();
    this.name = name.replace(reg[0], "").trim();
    return;
  }
  this.name = name;
}
```

La *célula* o *pelota de juego* es un círculo, y quiero que, al tener cierta *piel*, la célula tenga cierto color de borde. Para eso he usado:

```
if (this.name.indexOf("{chicken}") !== -1) {
  mainCtx.strokeStyle = "#D00606";
}
```

Pero el código no me funciona porque `indexOf()` no funciona cuando se esconde el nombre de la piel: como que no lo reconoce.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Si cambio la siguiente línea de la función:

```
this.name = name.replace(reg[0], "").trim();
```

Por esto:

```
 this.name = name.trim();
```

El borde sí funciona, pero la piel se ve en el nombre.

De nuevo, ¿qué puedo hacer?

---

Si se necesita mayor detalle, el código completo: http://ogar.pw/js/main_out.js?v62

Comment: 1. No uses mayúsculas. 2. Formatea bien el código.

Comment: @EduardoCampos lei varias veces tu pregunta y no puedo entender tu duda, porfavor mejora tu pregunta de tal modo que sea entendido por terceros.

Comment: Aver como te explico hmm , bueno quiero agregar un borde a un circulo dibujo en canvas , el borde se lo agregare siempre que el usuario tenga en el nombre {kraken} , hay una funcion que esconde los {} en el juego que la puse anteriormente , y por esto el indexOf no capta que el jugador se coloco {kraken} , y por ende no dibuja el fillStyle o borde.

Comment: @EduardoCampos, por favor edita tu pregunta, **los comentarios son temporales** además, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: si marcos muchisimas gracias

Comment: @EduardoCampos si la respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)** haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se [benefician](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)).

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista el problema es que:

- En `this.name` inicialmente tienes la "piel" del jugador.
- Luego "ocultas" la "piel" (en realidad la eliminas, este es el problema).

Cuando "ocultas" la piel, en `this.name` ya la "piel" no esta mas, ahora esta en `this.nameSkin`.

Solución:

- Método `setName`:

  ```
  setName: function(name) {
    var reg = /\{([\w]+)\}/.exec(name);
    if (reg && reg.length === 2) {
      this.nameSkin = reg[1].toLowerCase();
      this.name = name.replace(reg[0], "").trim();
      return;
   }
   // Si no tiene "piel"
   this.nameSkin = '';
   this.name = name;
  }
  ```
- Validación de "piel":

  ```
  // Usar "nameSkin"
  if (this.nameSkin.indexOf("chicken") !== -1) {
        mainCtx.strokeStyle = "#D00606";
  }
  ```

Comment: En vez de ver si coincide con `.exec()`, y luego reemplazar, podría reemplazarse directamente con `.replace()` utilizando la expresión regular como parámetro, evitando un paso --> `this.name = name.replace(/\{([\w]+)\} */, function (m, piel) { this.nameSkin = piel; return ""});`